# Lookup the dictionary with wildcards

Tags: macos, dictionary

Since wildcards aren't recognized by the GUI, is there another way?

[image]

Comment: Use an online dictionary that supports wildcards: [https://www.onelook.com](https://www.onelook.com)

Comment: I should have added: I need to do this offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line you can use `look` which looks for the string as a prefix of a word in the file- `/usr/share/dict/words`.

```
look ent
```

Right click the word in the Terminal window and select Look Up "....." menu or you can `grep` `/usr/share/dict/words` using regular expressions or extended regular expressions. Such as:

```
grep 'hello$' /usr/share/dict/words
```

Answer (score 1):

I never liked that the **Dictionary.app** in **macOS** does not support *wildcards* and while I mentioned in my comment to the OP to use and online dictionary that supports *wildcards*, I also searched **Google** for a *third-party app* that could be installed and didn't find any.

While one can easily *bookmark* the https://www.onelook.com **URL**, nonetheless, I decided to [appify](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=appify) it, using **AppleScript**, saving it as **Wildcard Dictionary Search.app**, so I could access it from the **Dock** or **Spotlight**, etc.

[image: Wildcard Dictionary Search]

Copy and paste the **AppleScript** *code* below into a new blank **Script Editor** *document* and save it as an application.

```
on run
    try
        tell current application
            activate
            set theSearchString to text returned of ¬
                (display dialog ¬
                    "Wildcard Dictionary Search:" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} ¬
                    default button 2 with title "https://www.onelook.com/?w=")
        end tell
        tell application "Safari"
            tell front window
                if theSearchString is not equal to "" then
                    set current tab to (make new tab with properties ¬
                        {URL:"https://www.onelook.com/?w=" & theSearchString})
                else
                    set current tab to (make new tab with properties ¬
                        {URL:"https://www.onelook.com"})
                end if
            end tell
        end tell
    on error eStr number eNum
        if eNum is not equal to -128 then
            display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum buttons {"OK"} ¬
                default button 1 with icon caution
            return
        end if
    end try
end run
```

---

Note that you can give it a custom icon and there are instructions on the Internet how to do that. I took the **Dictionary.icns** file from within the **Dictionary.app,** which is *red*, and using **Preview** to exported the 1024x1024 image as a **PNG**. I changed it to *blue* in [**GIMP**](https://www.gimp.org) by adjusting the Hue-Saturation on the *red* color. Then using instructions in [Create Your Own Custom Icons in OS X 10.7.5 or Later](https://blog.macsales.com/28492-create-your-own-custom-icons-in-10-7-5-or-later) I created a *blue* **Dictionary.icns** file, which I used to replace the **applet.icns** file within the **AppleScript** app, renaming it **applet.icns**.

Comment: My fault for not mentioning I need offline.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I created a handy little app doing exactly that: [wrdlr](https://itunes.apple.com/app/wrdlr/id1082481377?l=en&mt=12)

Answer (score 0):

Use `egrep` command in `Terminal`. It recognizes wildcards:

```
egrep "^..arl$" /usr/share/dict/words
```

The caret `^` tells `egrep` command to search for the string at the beginning of a line, and the dot `.` matches any character except a new line.

So, here are the results of a search:

```
gnarl
pearl
quarl
snarl
wharl
```

By using a question mark `?` you can even find words that may or may not have a characters:

```
egrep "^int..?$" /usr/share/dict/words
```

Result (here's `into` included):

```
inter
intil
into
intue
```

Also you can use this `bash alias`:

```
findword () { /usr/bin/grep ^"$@"$ /usr/share/dict/words ; }

findword '.ello'
```

Result:

```
cello
hello
```

Or you can search using `*` for all words ending in `mill` (including the word `mill` itself):

```
egrep '^.*mill$' /usr/share/dict/words

crabmill
crazingmill
graymill
gristmill
mill
overmill
pugmill
remill
sawmill
semimill
treadmill
walkmill
windmill
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer got down votes.

Comment: I think the same. I sure it's right answer))